# Busqueda de campos en sql server 2008 desde C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Mi problema es el siguiente:

tengo una conexión con una base da datos `sql server 2008` la cual me extrae un numero (manufacturing order) solo si ese numero esta en la base de datos, si el numero no se encuentra me envia un `Messagebox` donde me indica que el numero es invalido. el código corre bien, cuando yo dígito un numero que si se encuentra en la base de datos me hace lo que yo necesito y cuando el numero no se encuentra en la base de datos en me indica que el numero ni es valido pero solo si yo ingreso menos de 8 caracteres, si yo dígito 9 o mas el código no compila y me muestra un error en --> `if (reader1.Read() == false)`.

este es mi código...

```
class formclass
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    public string ordr ;
    public string prt ;


    public string limpio()
    {
        // limpiar el estring que se escanea para hacer procesos de busqueda
        ordr = Regex.Replace(ordr, @"^~200\|(.*)~$", "$1");
        //conectar con la base de datos para verificar si existe el manufacturing order id
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=misdatabase;Integrated Security=true;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand co = new SqlCommand("SELECT  mfgOrder.ManufacturingOrderId FROM ShopFloorControl.ManufacturingOrder_base mfgOrder WHERE mfgOrder.ManufacturingOrderId = '" + ordr + "'", con);
        using (SqlDataReader reader1 = co.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (co != null)
            {
                if (reader1.Read() == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Manufacturing Order invalid or empty", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        return ordr;
    }
```

si alguen puede ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: puedes especificar mas el mensaje de error?

Comment: no es un mensaje de error solo cuando esta compilando me duvuelve a ese if

Comment: eso quiere decir que tu reader de la consulta no encontro resultados...

Comment: si pero como hago para que ejecute el messagebox??

Comment: Se supone que si no encuentra resultados deberia hacer el show del messagebox pero tu pregunta dice que el codigo no compila.?

Comment: si yo digito un numero con 8  o  menos caracteres si funciona pero cuadoo digito 9 o mas se cae

Comment: *me muestra un error en* ¿Qué te muestra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, antes de todo debes validar el tamaño del campo en el `MaxLength` de tu TextBox para que asi no ingreses un número que no contemple el tamaño de tu campo si es un `CHAR(8)` en tu `TextBox` pones `MaxLength = 8`

Por otro lado antes de hacer el proceso que indicas debes preguntar en la db si ese número existe.

```
public static bool Exist(string numero)
    {
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE codigo=@numero";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numero", numero);

                var count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (count == 0)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Lo usas de la siguiente manera.

```
bool exist = Exist(numero);
            if(exist)
                //ME ESTRAE NÚMERO
            else
                //MUESTRO EL MESSAGEBOX
```

Por otro lado te recomiendo que encierres la conexión en un bloque `using`.

Al encerrar la declaración del objeto `Connection` entre un bloque `Using` ... `End Using`, nos estaremos asegurando de cerrar la conexión y de destruir los recursos utilizados por el objeto, al finalizar dicho bloque (cuando se ejecute `End Using`). Con ésto no tenemos que estar pendientes de llamar al método `Close` (para cerrar la conexión), ni tampoco al método `Dispose` (para destruir el objeto), por tanto, no es necesario disponer de un procedimiento externo para tales menesteres.